# Is there a possibility to avoid the xrefwrap error about void function returning a value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a vector defined like `std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions` and to store an item I use a function in this way:

```
template <typename Fun, typename Instance, typename ... Args>
void AddFunction(std::string name, Fun&& fun, Instance* instance, Args&& ... args)
{
  /*something is going on here*/
  functions.push_back(std::bind(fun, instance, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  /*something is going on here*/
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the function passed to `std::bind` can return some kind of value. I thought about using lambdas and I tried something like this

```
template <typename Fun, typename Instance, typename ... Args>
void AddFunction(std::string name, Fun&& fun, Instance* instance, Args&& ... args)
{
  /*something is going on here*/
  auto lambda = [&]() -> void
  {
    fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
  functions.push_back(std::move(lambda));
  /*something is going on here*/
}
```

but each time I try to use `AddFunction` an error message shows up saying that `term does not evaluate to a function taking n arguments` where `n` is the number of arguments that the function I pass to `AddFunction` takes.

Is there some workaround so that I can store items of type `std::function<void()>` even if the function stored returns a value?

Comment: `std::function<void()> f = [](){return 42;};` is valid...

Comment: It works with gcc. [LiveDemo](http://ideone.com/TWvrQX)

Comment: @Jarod42 Are you serious? Are you saying that this is a limitation of the Visual Studio compiler?

Comment: [It works with Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/LIWIU92295), too.

Comment: And so does [the version using lambdas](http://rextester.com/NYQ87259), once you correct your call. `fun` is a pointer-to-member, it cannot be called on its own. You are passing in `instance`, but your lambda version doesn't use it for anything - didn't you find that surprising? Make it `(instance->*fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], and what VS version?

Comment: I'm developing this solution on a really big project. It's impossible for me to actually give a working example. I'm using VS2013

Comment: @Agostino That kind of makes it difficult for us to answer right? Does Igor's example work on your compiler? If so, you need to come up with a short example that fails demonstrating your problem - otherwise we can't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both

```
functions.push_back(std::bind(fun, instance, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

and

```
  auto lambda = [&]() -> void
  {
    (instance->*fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
  functions.push_back(std::move(lambda));
```

work [just](http://rextester.com/LIWIU92295) [fine](http://rextester.com/NYQ87259) with Visual Studio.

Comment: I would like to use the first version. In my case it's not working and I don't know why. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Define "not working". Exactly what happens when you try?

Comment: With the first version, I have a compile time error when I try to use `AddFunction` with a function that returns `bool`. With the second version, I have a runtime error: when I try to actually use the function stored I have an access violation error, because the variable `instance` is null.

Comment: The lambda should be capturing by value, not by reference (`[=]` instead of `[&]`) - otherwise, it's capturing references to local variables which will very soon go out of scope and be destroyed. As to compiler error - would it be too much to ask to actually show the error message?

Comment: This is the compile error: `error C2562: 'std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<true,bool,std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__thiscall RHP::MachineController::* )(int),bool,RHP::MachineController,int>,Instance *&,_Ty>,false>::_ApplyX' : 'void' function returning a value`